# R neural networks linking different input to different hidden layers

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm trying to model a neural network like this :[image]

But in neuralnet package neural net formula has a syntax which can't be used for this kind of model as far as i can see.

```
net <- neuralnet(Output~LOC+PREC_n+FLEX_n+RESL_n,data, hidden=2) #, threshold=0.01)
```

This is the code i am using. For example, i want to link LOC and PREC_n inputs to first hidden layer and FLEX_n and RESL_n inputs to second. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out the solution. there is "exclude" in neuralnet functions parameters. you should specify weights which will be excluded in a matrix like this :

```
# exclude matrix
# first column is layer
# second column is input neuron
# third column is output neuron
# exclude links from first five neurons to second hidden neuron, links from last 17 neurons to first hidden neuron and output bias.
# ordering is as in weight vector
e = matrix( 
  c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
    2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,1,
    2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), 
  nrow=23, 
  ncol=3)
```

ordering -> connections from input neurons to first hidden neuron ( first connection is bias, so 1 is bias weight and 2 is first neuron's connection. that's why second column goes from 2....23). and goes along with this logic...